# Change whitespace symbols / glyphs in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Is there any way to change the symbols that Eclipse uses to represent whitespace characters? For example, I'd like to customise the newline glyph "¶" to something more like Notepad++ style "**LF**".

I know how to toggle them on and off and change the font, transparency, etc. But I haven't found any setting to actually change the symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. This kind of customization is not given. These options are hard coded in `org.eclipse.jface.text.WhitespaceCharacterPainter` class.

Need to tweak the source code to change whitespace, tab sign symbols etc.

---

```
  private static final char SPACE_SIGN= '\u00b7';
  private static final char IDEOGRAPHIC_SPACE_SIGN= '\u00b0';
  private static final char TAB_SIGN= '\u00bb';
  private static final char CARRIAGE_RETURN_SIGN= '\u00a4';
  private static final char LINE_FEED_SIGN= '\u00b6';
```

---

Also you can raise a eclipse bugzilla enhancement request [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Platform) to implement it.